Where are the "hidden" questions in [how-to-guide] tag?
I was interested in the kind of questions that would have the how-to-guide tag — there are 268 questions with this tag currently — but when I search with this tag, no questions are returned currently:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/how-to-guide
So, where are the "hidden" questions? (I don't know if it is a bug or just are deleted questions)

A search for is:article [how-to-guide] gives 104 results. It seems like they use a tag behind the scenes for that purpose...

Similar tag: [tag:knowledge-article]

May I ask why "articles" are counted as questions on the tag details page?.. Can it be somehow, uhm, made clear - like "0 questions, 268 articles are using this tag"? I'm glad that articles do not appear in regular searches, thanks for that, but hell, this mystery bugs me. Hurts me. I can't coexist with major discrepancies in summary statistics!

this is where I'd put my SEDE query for this... IF I HAD ONE >:(

@STerliakov probably an oversight. From what I understand the search for questions and posts of different kinds uses the same implementation and the database table where these are stored is also the same table. Articles were somewhat of a recent addition to this system, they did ensure the articles don't show up by default when searching but probably forgot to update the counting logic.

This same issue also stands for Staging Ground (They are included in the count on the tag details page), but doesn't apply to discussions for some reason.

This is probably due to the now long-standing bug (maybe for 2 years now) that has failed to properly garbage collect some tags when their question count reaches zero. AKA, this is a bug.

It seems that the 268 questions indicated are actually articles. These don't show up on the "questions tagged" page since it only shows questions and don't show up on the search page by default and need the is:article search operator to get them.
If you use the search string: is:article [how-to-guide] it returns 104 results. The remaining 164 from the 268 are probably draft / deleted articles, etc.

There are (currently) 26 deleted articles with the tag. I don't know where the remainder comes from.

@HenryEcker can moderators see draft articles as well? I believe there's a concept of drafts for articles.

@HenryEcker apparently there is a draft and a review state before an article is published according to this help center page

You have to be an Admin or RM to see drafts. I don't believe the diamond counts. Though it's also possible it's on some screen I've never been to in collectives. 138 drafts seems like an awfully high number for drafts. Though that's certainly a personal feeling; I don't really know how much engagement Articles gets as a product.
